# Docker php8.2-apache2 image is missing apache

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache2, docker-container

I try to use [php:8.2-apache](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/php/8.2-apache/images/sha256-89ad17cca246e8a6ce742b5b89ce65b34ce6223204a282e45f72b4f758ff6401?context=explore) image instead of building my own.

I run it via docker-compose as:

```
version: "3"
```

networks:
avto_next_network:
name: avto_next_network
driver: bridge

```
services:
 webserver2:
   image: php:8.2-apache
   networks:
      - avto_next_network
   links:
      - "db:db_local"
```

....... etc.

Next I do:

```
docker-compose up -d ; docker exec -it avto_php bash ; service --status-all
```

But there is no apache2 inside!
Am I supposed to install it on my own?
But what is the point then of this docker image?
Am I doing something wrong or that is raw image and better to use some other image?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I have tried `docker run -it --rm php:8.2-apache service --status-all` and it lists `apache2`.